# How do I color d3 bars with randomly generated data?

Tags: d3.js, colors, bar-chart

I'm trying to color each bar with a specified custom color. I've done this with real data up until this point by putting in a domain with data names and putting the colors in the range like this:

```
var colorBar = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"])
    .range(['#2fbcfc','#02a1e9','#6771DC', '#845EC2','#AD5EBA','#D65DB1', '#DC67AB', '#FF6F91']);
```

Then I would just call it like this:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return colorBar(d.name); })
```

I don't know how to call it now that the data is random or what to put in the domain.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/priglantonio/pen/VwZPBeR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the color of each bar to be based on its index, you could just modify your `colorBar` function to work with the index and pass that instead of the data:

```js
var dataset = [...some random numbers];

var colorBar = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length)) // returns [0, 1, 2, 3..., <dataset.length - 1>]
    .range(['#2fbcfc','#02a1e9','#6771DC', '#845EC2','#AD5EBA','#D65DB1', '#DC67AB', '#FF6F91']);

d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .style("background-color", (_, i) => colorBar(i));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I actually figured out an easier way.
I removed the domain completely and called the colors this way:
    .style("background-color", function(d) { return colorBar(d); })

I mean it's pretty much the same thing with a little less code.
Thanks though :).

Comment: Great! Just a word of warning -- since you're determining the color of the bar based on the data instead of the index, if you happen to have two bars with the same data, they will be the same color

Comment: But it does look like like you could use your approach (removing the domain), and just change your code slightly to pass the index instead of the data:

`.style("background-color", function(_, i) { return colorBar(i) })`